# Differing results summing Python arrays in terminal than in script

Tags: python, arrays

So I have two arrays defined as below:

```
particles=random.uniform(0,10, size=(100, 3))
displacement=random.uniform(-2, 2+1, size=(100, 3))
```

I want to redefine particles as their coordinate-wise sum. Simply typing

```
particles = particles + displacement
```

into the terminal gives me exactly what I want, but when I run my script, I get the error message:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (100,3) (1,300)

What is causing one of the arrays to change shape and why doesn't this happen in the terminal?

Edit: Here is the traceback:

```
File "<ipython-input-4-04059a7d3a12>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Garaidh/Documents/Python Scripts/3D Brownian 
Tree/3DBrownianTree_fork1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Garaidh/Documents/Python 
Scripts/3D Brownian Tree')

File "C:\Users\Garaidh\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Garaidh\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Garaidh/Documents/Python Scripts/3D Brownian 
Tree/3DBrownianTree_fork1.py", line 58, in <module>
particles=particles+displacement 
"""
something keeps fucking up here, I get an 
error that I don't get in the terminal
"""
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,3) 
(1,300)
```

and here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as random

from scipy.spatial import distance

t=0
patiencelevel=10000



region_length=100


seeds=[]
base_seed =[region_length/2,region_length/2,0];
seeds.append(base_seed)


particles=[]
numParticles=100
part_step=5



particle_Radius = 1


region_length=10
zero_array=np.zeros((numParticles, 3))
ceiling_array=np.full((numParticles, 3), region_length)
rad_array=np.full((numParticles, len(seeds)),particle_Radius)

particles=random.uniform(0,region_length, size=(numParticles, 3)) 

while len(particles)>0:
    displacement=random.uniform(-part_step, part_step+1, size= 
    (numParticles,3))
    particles=displacement+particles 
    """
    something keeps fucking up here, I get 
    an error that I do not get in the terminal    
    """
    particles=np.maximum(particles, zero_array)
    particles=np.minimum(particles, ceiling_array)
    particles=list(particles)

    templist=[]
    for j in range(0,len(seeds)): # for each seed
        for i in range(0,len(particles)):
            if distance.euclidean(particles[i],seeds[j]) 
            <=2*particle_Radius: 
                templist.append(particles[i]) 
    particles=[~np.in1d(particles,templist)]
    for x in templist:
        seeds.append(x) 
    if t > patiencelevel:
        break
```

Comment: The code works with me. The error must be caused by something else in your code.

Comment: Post the full traceback and if possible the code. There is no error in that line of code.

Comment: @raj I have attached the code. I'm fairly new to programming, so it may take me a minute to figure out how to get a traceback. I'll put it up when I figure it out.

Comment: @Daniel By "full traceback" we just mean the full error message. You posted part of it with "ValueError: operands could not...", but the full message will help us to help you.

Comment: @mypetlion Okay! I'll do that right away then.

Comment: I get the same error whether I run it from terminal or a .py file. Are you sure you're using the same version of Python when you run it each way? For example, are you maybe running it in terminal with Python 2 and from a script with Python 3?

Comment: @mypetlion I'm running everything in Spyder. The compiler runs Python 3.6. The terminal runs something called IPython. I'm not sure what version of Python that is.

Comment: @mypetlion Do you have any suggestions of other ways I might try to do the coordinate-wise sum with arrays in my script? I have a version that uses for loops, but I'm hoping to streamline things with arrays.